# 'transferring' StringBuilder contents to a new ArrayList in java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist, constants

If I have two class constants:

```
List<String> workingList= new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder holder = new StringBuilder(50);
```

both residing within, call it class `StringParser` and primary method `readStuff()`...

```
public class StringParser{

public void readStuff(){ 

//parsing logic and adding <String> elements to 
//said workingList...

}//end of method readStuff
```

followed by a method where I inspect the contents of `workingList`...

```
public String someReaderMethod()
{ 
  int ind = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < workingList.size();i++)
  {
    if(workingList.get(i).contains(someExp))
    {
      workingList.remove(ind);
      holder.append(workingList.get(i).toString());
}
else
{
   ++ind;
}
  }
   return holder.toString();
```

}

...given that `StringBuilder` holder now contains what `workingList` has removed, is there a way I can 'pass' the contents of `StringBuilder` to a new `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to use a StringBuilder? You can directly insert the values into a new ArrayList. I think you could do it in a simpler way.

```
List<String> discardedList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void readStuff() {}

public static List<String> someReaderMethod()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < workingList.size(); i++)
  {
    if(workingList.get(i).contains(someExp))
    {
      discardedList.add(workingList.get(i));
      workingList.remove(i);
    }
  }
  return discardedList;
}
```

Comment: that makes even more sense; I had tried that earlier and I could've sworn that it threw an exception but I shall try again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `deliminator` to parse string and then you can use `Split` method and convert String[] to ArrayList.

```
holder.append(tempList.get(i));
holder.append(";");//Deliminator
```

Now when you have to use it you need to do

```
String[] strings =holderString.split(";");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Comment: I went to correct your spelling, but double checked google, and learned a new, (albeit, made-up), word instead :) "[portmanteau, delimiter + eliminate] A string or pattern used to delimit text into fields, but which is itself eliminated from the resulting list of fields." from http://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/html/entry/deliminator.html

Answer (score 0):

While appending your List elements to your `StringBuilder` object, you need to append an extra delimiter after every append..

Later on, you can split the `String` in `StringBuilder` on that delimiter, and then convert your String array thus obtained to an `ArrayList`..